# request working on SQL/oracle but not on java Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following request which work fine in oracle :

```
SELECT SUM(col1_sum + col2_sum + col3_sum) AS sum_total FROM ( 
   SELECT 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN (col1 != 0) THEN 1 END) AS col1_sum, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN (col2 IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS col2_sum, 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN (col3 IS NULL OR col 3 < 0) THEN 1 END) AS col3_sum 
    FROM myTable)
;
```

It return the right sum according to all my condition

But when I translate it into HQL like this :

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(col1_sum + col2_sum + col3_sum) AS sum_total FROM ( "
   +"SELECT "
   +" COUNT(CASE WHEN (col1 != 0) THEN 1 END) AS col1_sum, "
   +" COUNT(CASE WHEN (col2 IS NULL) THEN 1 END) AS col2_sum, "
   +" COUNT(CASE WHEN (col3 IS NULL OR col 3 < 0) THEN 1 END) AS col3_sum "
   +"FROM myTable)")
```

I could compile my project without error, but when I launch it, I have the following error from hibernate :

`2018-03-08 11:18:54.485 [NO_USER NO_SESSION] ERROR o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter : line 1:96: unexpected token: (
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: (
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1544)
[....]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 96 [...]`

Apparently hibernate do not reconize my query after the `FROM (` on the first line

Is there any way to correctly convert my Oracle/SQL request into Hibernate/HQL ?

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate annotation for a native query using SQL rather than HQL is @NamedNativeQuery, not @Query.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Hibernate doesn't support subquery in the FROM clause. Refer to the discussion [Cannot use subqueries in from clause. Is there an alternativ](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=946290).

You may need to use @NamedNativeQuery that allows you to pass Native SQL, that way you can use subquery in FROM clause or see you rewrite your query without subquery in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I have found a way to do it without using @NamedNativeQuery. I had refactor my SQL query and apparently now Hibernate understand it correctly.

Now, on my java code, the query look like :

```
@Query("SELECT ((COUNT(CASE WHEN (col1 != 0) THEN 1 END)) + "
        + "(COUNT(CASE WHEN (col2 IS NULL) THEN 1 END)) + "
        + "(COUNT(CASE WHEN (col3 IS NULL OR col3 < 0) THEN 1 END))) AS total "
        + "FROM myTable")
```

It's work fine with that.
I think the issue was not the subquery in my requset (I have other request with subquery which work fine) but the "SUM" keyword.